# Select with multiple where on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a bunch of dogs divided into different colors: red, green and yellow.

```
Name    Color
---------------
Dog1    Green
Dog2    Green
Dog3    Yellow
Dog4    Yellow
Dog5    Red
Dog6    Red
etc.
```

Let's say that I have a table with 100 dogs, then I want them to be split into different heats with 4 dogs in each heat. The problem is that a red and a green dog should not be able to exist in the same heat.

I have tried with both MongoDB and SQL database but I have not been able to figure out if this is possible.

In SQL I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Dogs 
WHERE color IN ('green', 'yellow') OR color IN ('red', 'yellow')
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

But then red and green still can be selected together. Any one got some tips how to make this possible?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please don't tag to different technologies. If you have a SQL question then ask that of the appropriate audience. If you have a MongoDB or other engine question, then those are ["separate" questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) There is no such thing as it "all being the same" or any question which applies for "competing answers" of "which is best" between disparate engines.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your original table is called #temp:

```
    declare @holding table (name varchar(max), color varchar(max), heat int)
     declare @name varchar(max)
     declare @color varchar(max)
     declare @heat1 int
     declare @heat2 int
     declare @heat3 int
     declare @heat4 int
     declare @iterator int =1 
     while @iterator<=(Select  max(cast(replace(name,'dog','') as int))  from #temp)
     begin
     select @color= color, @name=name from #temp where name='dog'+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))
     select @heat1=count(*) from @holding where heat=1
     select @heat2=count(*) from @holding where heat=2
     select @heat3=count(*) from @holding where heat=3
     select @heat4=count(*) from @holding where heat=4

     if @color = 'red'
     begin
         if @heat1>=@heat2
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 2
         else 
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 1
     end

     if @color = 'yellow'
     begin
         if @heat1<=@heat2 and @heat1<=@heat3 and @heat1<=@heat4
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 1
         else if @heat2<=@heat1 and @heat2<=@heat3 and @heat2<=@heat4
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 2
         else if @heat3<=@heat1 and @heat3<=@heat2 and @heat3<=@heat4
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 3
         else
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 4
     end

     if @color = 'green'
     begin

         if @heat3>=@heat4
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 4
         else 
         insert @holding 
         select @name, @color, 3

     end

     set @iterator=@iterator+1
     end 

     select * from @holding 
     order by heat, color
```

Comment: Dont the yellow dogs get repeated here?

Comment: I think he only cares about red and green being separate

Comment: @DanielMarcus This only gives me four yellow dogs in heat1. I have a table with 100 dogs and want them all put into different heats, a dog should only be in one heat and also green and red dogs are not allowed in the same heat. I have no idea if that's even possible?

Comment: I see ok - are you using sql server?  if so you can loop through each one and decide on the fly which heat to put into

Comment: @DanielMarcus 
No I am not using an sql server but that sounds like a great idea! Do you have any tips or do you know of any tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: i can write it in sql server and u can adjust if you want - can you provide all the data we need to loop through?

Comment: The thing is that the application I want to create is to randomize heats before a competition and the number of dogs for each competition will be different just as which dogs enters the competition will be different from time to time...

Comment: thats fine i just need some sample data to work with- whatever the number is illl split it up into even heats where there are no red and green in same heat

Comment: Please provide as an insert statement so I can easily populate my table

Comment: INSERT INTO Dogs (name, color) VALUES ("Dog1", "Red"), ("Dog2", "Red"), ("Dog3", "Red"), ("Dog4", "Red"), ("Dog5", "Yellow"), ("Dog6", "Green"), ("Dog7", "Green"), ("Dog8", "Green"), ("Dog9", "Red"), ("Dog10", "Yellow"), ("Dog11", "Yellow"), ("Dog12", "Red"), ("Dog13", "Green"), ("Dog14", "Yellow"), ("Dog15", "Red"), ("Dog16", "Green"), ("Dog17", "Green"), ("Dog18", "Green"), ("Dog19", "Yellow"), ("Dog20", "Green")

Comment: OK please see updated code above.  When I tested on my end it worked well.  I was left with evenly distributed heats and no red/green in same heat.  Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna sound silly, but couldn't you just order by Color? Your heats would be boring like all green, all yellow, etc but it would solve your problem.

Maybe something like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN Color = 'Yellow' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END END AS o FROM dogs 
) x ORDER BY x.o
```

Comment: Yes I guess that actually will solve my problem, thanks! The only thing is, how I should handle if i have 5 yellow dogs left. Since there should only be 4 dogs in a heat, how should I handle that last dog... it should be put with in a green or red heat, which ever needs more dogs in a heat.

Comment: yeah I am kind of curious about that. First, I assume we know the total number of dogs is a multiple of 4, right? That would mean that you could never have 5 dogs left. The query I wrote would order dogs GGGYYYRR, if we assume the number is divisible by four and the solution is possible (cause, for example GGRR is unsolvable) then this method produces a solution.

Comment: The thing is that the application I want to create is to randomize heats before a competition and the number of dogs for each competition will be different just as which dogs enters the competition will be different from time to time...